# AWS DocumentDB Spring Boot @Transactional Not Working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, aws-documentdb

I have a spring boot app and I am connected to AWS DocumentDB.My MongoDB URI looks like the following:

`hostname:27017/test?ssl=true&retryWrites=false&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred`

I am using DocumentDB docdb 4.0.0 and my mongoDB drivers are also >= 4.0.0

It means that DocumentDB is replicaSet enabled which is a pre-requisite to perform transactions as mentioned in the docs.

This is my DocumentDB Config class

```
DocumentDBConfig.java

@Bean
MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory db) {
    TransactionOptions txnOptions = TransactionOptions.builder()
            .readPreference(ReadPreference.primary())
            .readConcern(ReadConcern.LOCAL)
            .writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY)
            .build();
    MongoTransactionManager mongoTransactionManager = new MongoTransactionManager(db, txnOptions);
    return mongoTransactionManager;
}
```

I will just perform a simple test. Let's say I have a service class(PersonServiceClass)

```
@Service
public void PersonService() {

    PersonRepository personRepo;

    PersonService(PersonRepository repo) {
        this.personRepo = repo;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void add() {
        Person personOne = new Person();
        personRepo.save(personOne);
        int x = 5/0;
        Person personTwo = new Person();
        personRepo.save(personTwo);
    }

}
```

I expected the PersonOne to get rolled back. However, it didn't roll back which is a major bug.

I tested the exact setup with MongoDB which was running locally. I also enabled replicaSet in MongoDB. When I ran the above test, it was able to roll back successfully.

Comment: Are the PersonRepository or its save() method further annotated? Are you calling the add() method from another component?

Comment: PersonRepository and its save() are not further annotated. I am not calling add() from another component.

Comment: @dcolazin I tested the exact setup with mongoDB running locally and it worked correctly. Rollback happened successfully